# Laravel Query Builder - How can I sum?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm logging time entries for users for each month of the year. The times are in the following format: hh:mm:ss

example: 08:32:00

Here's how i'm grouping my months together:

```
  $data = $user->times()->whereYear('start_day', 2019)->get();
        $group_months = $data->groupBy(function($entry) {
             return Carbon::parse($entry->start_day)->format('m');
      });
```

How can I sum $group_months, so I can the total time value for each month?

Here's my migration for times

```
Schema::create('times', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->date('start_day');
            $table->text('category');
            $table->time('start_time');
            $table->time('finish_time');
            $table->time('duration');
            $table->text('notes');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

Comment: so you want example january = 20, february= 50 ... like that? show your table i will help you

Comment: Yea exactly! Posted my table in op.
Edit: I should probably mention, I want to group the totals by month and category, but I haven't figured out how to group them by categories yet.

So example: 
January - Vacation Time: 50
January - Overtime: 25
February - Overtime: 25

But i'm fine with just the monthly total, I can figure out the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$monthDurations = $user->times()
    ->whereYear('start_day', 2019)
    ->select(
        \DB::raw('SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration)) as `month_duration_in_seconds`'),
        \DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_day, "%Y-%m") as `year_month`'),
        'category',
        'user_id'
    )
    ->groupBy(\DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_day, "%Y-%m")'), 'category', 'user_id')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

This has not been tested. However you should be able to achieve this with the following:

```
$data = $user->times()
    ->whereYear('start_day', 2019)
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($entry) {
        return Carbon::parse($entry->start_day)->format('m');
    })->map(function ($times, $month) {
        $seconds = $times->map(function ($time, $key) {
            return \Carbon::parse($time->start_time)->diffInSeconds(\Carbon::parse($time->finish_time));
        })->sum();

        return gmdate('H:i:s', $seconds);

    })->all();
```

After grouping the month, you can use the `->map()` collection method to get the difference in seconds for reach of the times within the month.

You can then add the all up using `->sum()`.

Finally you can use `gmdate()` to convert `$seconds` to the required format.

I hope this helps.

**Note:** This assumes that the `finish_time` does not go past the `start_day` specified on the record.