# Laravel - Calculating total time for multiple time-entries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, eloquent

I'm logging user time entries. My times migration looks like:

```
  Schema::create('times', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->date('start_day');
            $table->text('category');
            $table->time('start_time');
            $table->time('finish_time');
            $table->time('duration');
            $table->text('notes');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        });
    }
```

**Note: Duration calculates total difference between start_time and finish_time**

I'm grouping the months and categories together with the following code:

```
   $data = $user->times()->whereYear('start_day', 2019)->get();
        $group_months = $data->groupBy(function($entry) {
            return $entry->category;
        })->map(function($items) {
            return $items->groupBy(function($entry) {
                return Carbon::parse($entry->start_day)->format('m');
            })
        ->map(function($items) {
            return $items->count();
            });
        });
```

If I run dd($group_months) I get this:

```
Collection {#322 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    "Comp Time Used" => Collection {#318 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        10 => 2
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So as you can see, it groups it by the category and month and counts the total number of entries.

I want to now get the total time duration for each month and it's corresponding category.

So for example, If we reference the collection above I have:
**2 Time Entries for October under Comp Time Used.**

Lets say, Time Entry 1 duration = 12:00:00 and Time Entry 2 duration = 05:00:00

I want the total duration to display: 17:00:00. How can I do this?

Comment: I answered your other question. Did you see my answer?https://stackoverflow.com/a/58435270/9396711

Comment: I didn't see it, my bad. Would I put that inside of my Time.php model?

Comment: Try calling this code in your controller.

Comment: Gives me an SQL syntax/version error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected and checked my previous answer.

```php
$monthDurations = $user->times()
    ->whereYear('start_day', 2019)
    ->select(
        \DB::raw('TIME_FORMAT(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(duration)), "%H:%i:%s") as `month_duration`'),
        \DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_day, "%Y-%m") as `year_month`'),
        'category',
        'user_id'
    )
    ->groupBy(\DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_day, "%Y-%m")'), 'category', 'user_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, yea that works, I just need to convert that seconds time into a format like this: 39600 seconds = 11 because 39600 = 11:00:00. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: I changed my answer. Check it.